# В чем суть MVPVM?

Tags: архитектура, mvp

***MVPVM*** - это комбинация ***MVP*** и ***MVVM***, с целью разграничить `Model` и `ViewModel`. `Data Binding` также работает между `View` и `ViewModel`.

Мне не понятно:

1. Кто будет посылать `View` "сообщение о том, что нужно обновить интерфейс": `Presenter` или `ViewModel`?
2. Представим, что пользователь нажал на кнопку, кто получит об этом информацию, понятно что `ViewModel` (`Data Binding`) и передаст инфу к `Presenter` для обработки, или сразу получит эту информацию `Presenter` от `View`?

Все диаграммы путают меня.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. Кто будет посылать `View` "сообщение о том, что нужно обновить интерфейс": `Presenter` или `ViewModel`?

Также как и в MVP, это обязанность `Presenter`'а. `Presenter` решает, когда и как обновить интерфейс на основе изменений в данных или пользовательских действий.

> 2. Представим, что пользователь нажал на кнопку, кто получит об этом информацию, понятно что `ViewModel` (`Data Binding`) и передаст инфу к `Presenter` для обработки, или сразу получит эту информацию `Presenter` от `View`?

Пользовательское действие (нажатие на кнопку) будет обработано `View` и передано `Presenter`'у для дальнейшей обработки. `Presenter` может решить, нужно ли обновить данные в `Model` или `ViewModel` и, соответственно, обновить View.
`ViewModel` и `Presenter` могут взаимодействовать между собой, но их основные обязанности разделены. `ViewModel` отвечает за предоставление данных и логику для отображения, а `Presenter` — за обработку пользовательских действий и управление обновлениями интерфейса.